# If $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact, prove $A\cap B$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a metric space such that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact, then $A\cap B$ is compact.

I'm trying to prove first that $A\cap B$ is closed and go from there. The question doesn't explicitly state that the metric space has the Heine Borel property so I think I would be incorrect in assuming so to solve the problem.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I'm trying to show first that A∩B is closed and go from there...

Comment: Are we assuming the metric space has the Heine Borel property.  If so $A$ and $B$ are closed so $A\cap B$ is closed.  ANd $B$ is bounded so $A\cap B$ is bounded... But if the metric space doesn't have the Heine Borel property we must do something else....

Comment: @fleablood The question doesn't explicitly state that the metric space has the Heine Borel property... it was one of the last theorems we learned but I'm unsure if I would be correct in making that assumption.

Comment: Yeah,... me too.  Find an open set $K$ that contains all of $A\setminus B$ but none of $B$.  (I'm not sure how or if we can verify such a set exists.  Then if $\{O_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $A\cap B$ then $\{[O_\alpha \cup K]\}$ is an open cover of $B$.  Thus has a finite subcover $\{[O_i\cup K]\}$.  ANd so $\{O_i\}$ is a finite subcover and so compact.  Just not sure how to prove every open set in an an open cover can expand to include the rest of A.

Comment: Do you have available a (standard) result that says that in a topological space:  a closed subset of a compact set is itself compact?

Comment: @c87 Your answer received a downvote and a vote to close, probably because you did not input any attempt of solving the question in the question itself (or some other meaningful context). These kinds of questions are a little frowned upon in this site. By your comments, I can tell that you understand the subject and isn't simply looking for "an answer at all costs/solve my homework". In the future, try putting the context which you further elaborated in the comments in the question itself. If possible, do this also for this question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Your question" in the beginning of this last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good idea of going for the fact that $A \cap B$ is closed.

$A \cap B$ is closed in the subspace topology of $B$, since $A$ is closed. Since $B$ is compact, we have that $A \cap B$ is compact: this is due to the fact that a closed set inside a compact set is compact.

---

If you know a little bit of general topology, you will realize that the above argument avoids using the fact that $B$ is closed, which is not valid in a general topological space (compactness *and* Hausdorffness can guarantee that). The argument is readily seen then to hold also for a general topological space.

Also, it may be a good exercise to keep careful track of what "topology level" (i.e., if we are on $X$ or $B$) each argument relies, and when this makes a difference or not.

Comment: I believe I know what the downvote is for: this question looks like a PSQ. However, if you see the comments, OP looks like he has tried something and has a reasonable understanding of the subject, as his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667748/if-a-is-closed-and-b-is-compact-prove-a-cap-b-is-compact/2667823#comment5510681_2667748) implies.

If the downvote is for another reason (an inaccuracy in the answer or other thing), please elaborate if possible.

Comment: You've only prove $A\cap B$ is closed in $B$, not in $X$ and therefore that $A\cap B$ is compact in $B$ and not in $X$.  I imagine that is the downvote.

Comment: @fleablood Compactness is intrinsic (if a set is compact in a subspace, it is compact in the space), this is part of the "good exercise" I referred to. "Compactness in $B$/in $X$" is essentially a mute question.

Comment: And as a sidenote, since I talk about the case of a general topological space in the answer, $A \cap B$ may *not* be closed in $X$ if $X$ is not Hausdorff. Take $X$ any infinite set with the trivial topology, $B$ a finite non-empty subset, and $A:=X$. $A \cap B$ is not closed in $X$.

Comment: @c87 There is a theorem of metric spaces (and sort of the definition in topological ones) that a set is open (resp. closed) in a subspace with the induced metric if and only if it is the intersection of an open (resp. closed) set in the original space with the subspace.

Comment: And that's probably the way to go.  It's work but .... well, I think at least the OP has  a direction now.  (It's more than I want to do in the morning with my coffee.)

Comment: We haven't covered that yet. But, it's definitely helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a metric space. A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is sufficient.

> *Definition*
>
> Let be $B\subset X$ and $(\mathcal O_i)_{i\in I}$ an open cover of $B$ with some index set $I$. $B$ is called compact if there exists $J\subset I$ finite such that $(\mathcal O_j)_{j\in J}$ is an open cover of $B$.

To prove that $A\cap B$ is compact, you have to consider an open cover $(\mathcal O_i)_{i\in I}$ of $A\cap B$. Next, $O:=X\setminus A$ is open, since $A$ is closed and $\{O\}\cup(\mathcal O_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $B$, since $$
B=(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)\subset(X\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)=O\cup(A\cap B)\subset O\cup\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal O_i
$$

Here the rest:

> Since $B$ is compact, there exists an finite cover out of $\{O\}\cup (\mathcal O_i)_{i\in I}$. This implies two cases.
>
> **Case 1:** There exists $i_1,\ldots,i_k\in I$ such that $B\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^k \mathcal O_{i_n}$.
>
> Using $A\cap B\subset B$, we get $A\cap B\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^k \mathcal O_{i_n}$. Hence $(\mathcal O_{i_n})_{n=1}^k$ is a finite subcover of $A\cap B$.
>
> **Case 2:** There exists $i_1,\ldots,i_k\in I$ such that $B\subset O\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^k \mathcal O_{i_n}$.
>
> Using $A\cap B\subset B$, we get $A\cap B\subset O\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^k \mathcal O_{i_n}$. Since $(A\cap B)\cap O\subset A\cap (X\setminus A)=\emptyset$, we get further $A\cap B\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^k \mathcal O_{i_n}$. So $(\mathcal O_{i_n})_{n=1}^k$ is a finite subcover of $A\cap B$.
>
> Both cases imply the compactness of $A\cap B$.

Comment: It'd be *really* helpful if you used the same variables as the original problem.  How do you know $A \cap B$ is closed?

Comment: I think I see where you're going, but I am definitely a bit confused by your use of $K$ and $J$ in the definition, and then $A$ and $K$ in the following portion. Are you saying in this case that my $A$ subset is the $J$ subset from the definition?

Comment: @fleablood You are right. I changed my notation. Why should I prove that $A\cap B$ is closed? I worked directly with the definition of compactness in a topological space.

Comment: @c87: I changed my notation. Sry for that. $I$ and $J$ are index sets. $I$ is an arbitrary index set. The definition of compactness says that for every open cover exists a finite subcover. So finitely many of those open sets are sufficient to cover the set. To prove compactness for $A$, we take an open cover of $A$ and construct an open cover of $B$, use the compactness of $B$ and conclude that you get an finite cover of $A$.

Comment: Because you said "to prove J is compact" and "J is closed" and since we are trying to prove $A\cap B$ is compact I assumed you meant $J$ to represent $A\cap B$.  We can't prove $A$ is comapact because... it doesn't have to be.  Consider $B= [0,3]$ and $A =(-\infty, 2]$ then $A\cap B = [0,2]$.  It'd be impossible and useless to prove A is compact because it isnt.

Comment: But that is a finite cover of *ONE* open cover of $A$ not all open covers.  The only thing we know of $A$ is it is closed.  We *can't * prove it is compact because it might not be.

Comment: @fleablood You are right. Shame on me. Somehow I thought that there is $A\subset B$... Ok, I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. We have been working with open subcovers and covers and this may not have been the way I originally thought to work through it, but it makes sense to me.